# Error "parent key and child key are identical" using single table as Parent and Child tables for Nested Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, parent-child, repeater

I am working with an outer and inner repeater. The first lists "company name". Second lists "tasks" completed for that company. For each company there are many tasks. This is my first time working with nested repeaters.

The issue is, I am using one table ("Tracker"). Column CompanyName comes from Table1("Tracker") as does Task, every example I have worked with uses two tables. When creating the relation I get error "parent key and child key are identical"

```
    ds.Relations.Add("myrelation", _
    ds.Tables("Tracker").Columns("CompanyName"), _
    ds.Tables("Tracker").Columns("CompanyName"))
    PRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tracker")
```

**Is there a way around this? Another way to do it? Other than make another Database? VB or C# is fine**.

Here is the entire Sub that I call on a btn click and the aspx section if that helps.

```
    Protected Sub bindParent()

    conn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connString")
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Tracker", conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    cmd1.Fill(ds, "Tracker")

    Dim cmd2 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Tracker", conn)
    cmd2.Fill(ds, "Tracker")
    ds.Relations.Add("myrelation", _
    ds.Tables("Tracker").Columns("CompanyName"), _
    ds.Tables("Tracker").Columns("CompanyName"))
    PRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tracker")

    PRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tracker")
    Page.DataBind()

    conn.Close()

    End Sub
```

aspx

```
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlCompany" runat="server" visible="false"/>         
        <asp:Repeater ID="PRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompanyName") %></b>
            </tr>

                <asp:Repeater ID="childRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("myrelation") %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Container.DataItem("Task")%><br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

*This is the example I worked from
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;326338

Comment: The `Relations.Add` call makes no sense - you don't need to add a relation, all the data is in the same table?

Comment: Yes its all on the same table. Do you have any ideas here?

Comment: The point of a relation is to make the second table a hierarchical child of the first one, hierarchy determined by the specified key. The example you are following uses two tables and two repeaters - you only need one repeater if you only have one table.

Comment: For the structure I want I think this was the right way to do this. I needed to rename my datasets. You can use one table.

Comment: @ReeceZimm Instead of editing your solution into your question, please post an answer with the solution. You'll then be able to accept your own answer.  For the time being, I've removed your answer from the question and posted a CW answer with the contents.

Comment: It wasn't allowing me to accept my own answer at that time. Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this gave me the output I wanted and no more error message

```
Dim cmd1 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select distinct CompanyName from Tracker", conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet()
cmd1.Fill(ds, "Company")

Dim cmd2 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Tracker", conn)
cmd2.Fill(ds, "Tracker")

ds.Relations.Add("myrelation", _
ds.Tables("Company").Columns("CompanyName"), _
ds.Tables("Tracker").Columns("CompanyName"))
PRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables("Company")
PRepeater.DataBind()

conn.Close()
```

<sup>*moving solution from question to answer</sup>